# Where to put variables to use vue-analytics to track user-ID in google analytics?

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics, single-page-application

I have created a single page app using vue.js. I need to track my logged in users in google analytics. I can do this by sending a User-ID variable back to google analytics. I have done this before by simply setting the variable and sending it back to google analytics.

This time I am using Vue.js and for my analytics and I am using a very nice plug in [MatteoGabriele/vue-analytics](https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-analytics).

My problem is I don't know how or where to set my User-ID variable in my code.

Comment: Do you take a look into [**Get started** page](https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-analytics/blob/master/docs/installation.md)?

Answer (score 1):

Have been trying to figure out the same question, and from closed issues [79](https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-analytics/issues/79), and [178](https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-analytics/issues/178), this looks like the suggested method.

```
this.$ga.set('userId', 123456)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install vue-analytics first,

run `npm install vue-analytics`

then, in your app.js or main.js import vueAnalytics

`import VueAnalytics from 'vue-analytics';`

and then,

`Vue.use(VueAnalytics, {
  id: 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-x', router
});`

Remember to replace the 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-x' with your Tracking ID.

for better understanding use the vue-analytics [documentation](https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-analytics/blob/master/docs/installation.md)